# Setting Data in ViewPagerIndicatorin different layouts

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have 3 different layouts on my ViewPagerIndicator - https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

My project is to load data from the website and set the data accordingly into the 3 different layout of the ViewPager.

How do I go about achieving it?

In my TestFragment, I have

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("mContent", mContent);
        View view = null;
        if (mContent.equalsIgnoreCase("title1")) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);

        } else if (mContent.equalsIgnoreCase("title2")) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false);
        } else if (mContent.equalsIgnoreCase("title3")) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, container, false);
            //Textview data = (TextView)view.findViewById(id)
        }
        return view;
    }
```

I know this is for setting layout according to the fling'd titles.
I know how to findViewById to get the id of the widgets and set data. However, the data is set statically in the code itself.

For me, I have to grab data from the internet and put the data in accordingly. How do I achieved that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your question you link to the `ViewPagerIndicator` and speak about setting the data/layout(?!) in the `ViewPager`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I meant the FragmentPager.

Comment: you want increase ViewPagerIndicator when data is extends ?

Answer (score 1):

I almost know what you want.Here is my answers,and it works well.
You can according to the following steps.

1.Create three different Fragment class ,such as LoadImageFragment1,LoadImageFragment2,LoadImageFragment3, and all of them extends Fragment.
Follow is my example.

```
public class LoadImageFragment1 extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
LoadImageAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mInflater = inflater;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loadimage_layout, null);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new LoadImageAdapter();
    adapter.initList();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

private class LoadImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void initList(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 30;i ++){
            list.add("" + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.loadimage_item, null);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

2.Then modify your SampleTabsDefault class.

```
    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      //  return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            return new LoadImageFragment1();
        case 1:
            return new LoadImageFragment2();
        case 2:
            return new LoadImageFragment3();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

And I just use the class of SampleTabsDefault as a sample.You can do this in other classes.
Here I just use a ListView as a sample , you can load your images and texts from internt, and you also can do other things in your LoadImageAdapter 's getView() method.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Sorry for my poor of English comunication, GoogleMusicAdapter is a inner class of SampleTabsDefault.And you can find them in ViewPagerIndicator - https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 different layouts on my ViewPagerIndicator

ViewPagerIndicator is just an **indicator**

I thought your meaning is your viewadapter have three views to show.

Use [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to handle different view.
you should read the ViewPagerIndicator [samples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsStyled.java)

Answer (score 0):

Before starting, copy the samples from ViewPagerIndicator 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample

The steps to be done are,

1. Create an custom FragmentPagerAdapter (ex: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/TestFragmentAdapter.java)
2. Create custom Fragment for each each layout (in your case 3)
   https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/TestFragment.java
3. Override `onActivityCreated` in the fragment class

In the `onActivityCreated` method, u can access the UI components as in `onCreate` method

So that u can make a web service call, bind it to ur UI components in this segment.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Create and implement a `Loader` (`AsyncTaskLoader`) to load data from the internet.

Have your `TestFragment` implement `LoaderCallbacks`, so that it gets notified when the `Loader` (`AsyncTaskLoader`) has finished loading data from the internet.

In your implementation of your TestFragment's `onActivityCreated`, initialize or restart the loader:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

In your `TestFragment`'s implementation of onLoadFinished, assign the data to the widgets.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html